# Regex to match ASCII non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match ASCII non-alphanumeric characters. The regex should not match non-ASCII characters. I am using the following:

```
   "[\\u0000-\\u002f\\u003a-\\u0040\\u005b-\\u0060\\u007b-\\u007f]"
```

Can I simplify this regex ?

Comment: why `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` doesn't work?

Comment: @user3218114, "should not match non-ASCII characters."

Comment: Are you looking for single ASCII non-alphanumeric character match only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use a character class intersection. Example:

```
[\\p{ASCII}&&\\P{Alnum}]
```

This means: intersection between all ascii characters and all non alphanumeric characters

Comment: Thanks but I need to match ASCII and _non_-alphanumeric characters. So the `"[\\p{ASCII}&&[^\\p{Alnum}]]"` will probably work.

Comment: @Michael `\P` is the opposite of `\p`.

Comment: @Michael However since most of the time you'd favour readability, while this regex is shorter, you will find yourself using negated classes in sets more in the future. aka `[a&&[^\s]]` > `[a&&\S]`.

Comment: Thanks again. You are probably right about using of negated classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex in Java

```
^(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z]+$)\p{ASCII}+$
```

OR else:

```
^(?!\p{Alnum}+$)\p{ASCII}+$
```

Comment: Yes it OP uses them in `matches` method then anchors aren't needed. But if it is used in other methods like `find` then probably needed.

Comment: The OP was talking about matching a single character, which would be `(?!\p{Alnum})\p{ASCII}`.  To enforce that condition on the whole string, you would do this: `^(?:(?!\p{Alnum})\p{ASCII})+$`.  Your regexes match a string that's all ASCII but not all alphanumeric (that is, it must contain at least one non-alphanumeric character).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set intersection:

```
"[\\p{ASCII}&&[^\\p{Alnum}]]"
```

Read: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Great ! Thank you. Looks like exactly what I need. Too bad it is not a _standard_ regex.

Comment: @Michael There is no such thing as a _standard_ regular expression ever since programmers overuse it for everything - Writing the one-liner regex is often more viable than writing an entire finite state machine to parse!