# match ASCII characters except alphanumeric

Tags: java, regex

I have a question that come to my mind when I answered this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349213/regex-to-match-ascii-non-alphanumeric-characters) to match ASCII characters except alphanumeric.

This is what I have tried but it's not correct.

```
(?=[\x00-\x7F])[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vG0nE6/3)

I am not looking for solution, just want to know, where I am wrong. What is the meaning of this regex pattern?

Thanks

---

As per my understanding `(?=[\x00-\x7F])` is used to check for ASCII character and `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is used to exclude alphanumeric character. So finally it will match any ASCII character except alphanumeric. Am I right?

Comment: It's because you test only one character in a global research, not the whole string from begining to end.

Comment: Is it fine for single character?

Comment: yes. If you want to test the whole string in the same way, you must write `\A(?:(?=[\x00-\x7F])[^a-zA-Z0-9]))+\z`

Comment: That's the only thing.

Comment: @Unihedron yes that's correct but when I uses it in the program.

Comment: @Unihedron - Only if you are expressing the regex as a Java string literal.  He isn't doing that here ... is he.

Comment: Why do you say it’s not correct? It looks okay to me. `£` isn’t an ASCII character.

Comment: @matt I got -2 that's why I assumed it.

Answer (score 1):

The regex parser goes to each character in the string and checks it with the regex.

The first part, `(?=...)`, is called a 'lookahead', and it asks if the next character is whatever specified (that is, `[\x00-\x7F]`). It *doesn't* move the character pointer.

The next part is saying that the next character is not alphanumeric, but *does* move the character pointer.

So it does precisely what you told it to; that is, match any non-alphanumeric ASCII character.

It does not match `£` in `££££A$££0#$%` because `£` is not ASCII. If you want to match ANY character that is non-alphanumeric, you're probably looking for this regex:

```
`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and other pages on the site for more info.

Comment: I know `£` is not an ASCII character but my question is about *match ASCII characters except alphanumeric*. So any ASCII character other than `[a-zA-Z0-9]` should be matched. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will match `non-ASCII` character as well that I don't want to match.

Comment: I  don't want to match **ANY character** that is non-alphanumeric.

Comment: @user3218114 ...But then your original code works. ?_?

Comment: I just answered the same answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349213/regex-to-match-ascii-non-alphanumeric-characters) but I got -2 votes that's why I asked it here to confirm it again. Thanks for your time. I don't why people down votes without any comments?